# how create best schema database with ratings system and available in month?

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine, schema

i will create schema the database MySQL. There are username, password etc and rating system and available in month. 
Standard it looks like this:

```
id | username | password | january | february | march     | rating1 | rating2| rating3 |
1  | john     |  xxx     | 1       |  0       | 1         |  3      | 3      | 6
2  | amy      |  xxx     | 1       |  1       | 0         |  1      | 6      | 3
```

if a user buys article then must add a rating (1,2,3). if chose 2 in John then  rating2 +1

```
id | username | password | january | february | march     | rating1 | rating2| rating3 |
1  | john     |  xxx     | 1       |  0       | 1         |  3      | 4      | 6
2  | amy      |  xxx     | 1       |  1       | 0         |  1      | 6      | 3
```

january, february (1 - available, 0 - not available)etc set himself John or Amy.

this is good? Should I create separate tables for Januar/feb/march and rating1/2/3? Maybe only for rating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im not a hard core database designer but at a glance this is schema is not normalized.

if you can create a separate table for month and rating would be better please find the below sample

d | username | password

1  | john     |  xxx
2  | amy      |  xxx

id | month | rating

1  | 1     | 3

MonthID | MonthName

1       | January

How ever this sujjestion may not be the ideal solution for your proposed database.

Answer (score 0):

OK I know this is late but this is very serious!!!

First use bcrypt for encrypting passwords

Second NEVER store a password that is not encrypted properly.  You need a "salt" to do this correctly.

See here:  http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/13/php-bcrypt-hash-a-password-with-a-logical-salt

I'm not a php guy but it looks good.

As for the DB, Prabhakantha's answer looks OK but might not be complete suitable.

Users

```
id | username | password | salt

1  | john     | xxx      | blah
2  | amy      | xxx      | ughh
```

ratings

```
id | month_id | rating
1  | 1        | 3
```

Months

```
id | month   | year
1  | January | 1990
```

I know in the ruby on rails world I would model this with a polymorphic association.  Take a look how that works here:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Yes it is a video on rails but it applies here.